# How can I get my page headers to resize using responsive layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a site that I need to be functional both on mobile devices and on computers. I'm using bootstrap-responsive and have gotten a lot of things to work. Currently I'm working on the hero-unit for the front page. I have a page header that I would like to auto-scale according to screen size. The main bootstrap site (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) makes use of something like what I want to do with their main page header. Any help is appreciated.

Relevant Code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="hero-unit">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Page Header</h1>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu dolor, dictum scelerisque gravida nec, vulputate in odio. Pellentesque sagittis ipsum et mauris elementum vitae molestie ipsum blandit. Mauris tempus hendrerit arcu, sed vestibulum justo tempor a. Praesent sit amet odio ligula. Morbi sit amet leo vestibulum neque bibendum ullamcorper sed ut ante. Vestibulum id diam quis ipsum aliquet vestibulum. Donec vulputate auctor pharetra.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Learn More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

EDIT: Here's another example of it. http://www.screenlight.tv/
If you resize your window on that page, the header resizes accordingly. I've tried looking at the source and I'm having a hard time finding it.

Comment: Post some relevant code so we can take a look.

Comment: Dd you add the responsive CSS to your page? It's not included in the default CSS.

Comment: Yeah I have. Other responsive features are working. Is this definitely part of bootstrap-responsive?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Okay I've figured this one out. For future reference, this is done using the `@media(max-width:  )` property. So for instance, you would do:

```
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}
```

Or whatever you need to do. Hope this helps someone in the future! Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

If it's an image header photo (no text involved), using `class="img-responsive" as well works. I.e:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
 <img src="/images/sample_photo.jpg" class="img-responsive">
 </div>
</div>
```

Live sample here: http://www.bootply.com/Cc0rdXsJXP

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried switching it to

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's supposed to be container-fluid. I copied their bootstrap stylesheet which is essentially bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css mashed into one file and tried it and it works, but I still don't get why mine won't work.

Comment: do you happen to have this online anywhere we could take a look?

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5429), bootstrap doesn't currently support responsive font size out of the box. The already shown `@media(max-width: )` is the way to go.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "The already shown…" and/or add more code to demonstrate the solution.