# Twitter Bootstrap banner image resizing

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to make a layout page, which has a banner at the top, that handles the following:

Desktop - Maximized screen (Would have a center page used of 1024px limited)
Desktop - as soon as the size goes lower than 1024, the banner scaled down, to fit the width of the screen
Phone/Mobile - Banner uses full width

Below is a technically rendered diagram, using software which is beyond any of your imaginations, so I will not elaborate, but hopefully it get's the point across.

First box shows a screen with the browser maximized. Banner goes to 1024 max, as does the content of the screen below it.

Next image shoes a 1024 resolution screen. Screen uses full browser.

Last image down shows a screen, with the browser NOT maximized, and using less than 1024 pix. The banner resizes down (doesn't crop... resizes)

And the bottom right is a phone. No brand... just a phone. :)

[image]

Can you show how this can done? Can the image (an ?) be resized based on these requirements?

My attempt at the moment:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <img class="item active img-responsive fullsize" src="/Content/images/1.jpg" />
                <img class="item img-responsive fullsize" src="/Content/images/2.jpg" />
                <img class="item img-responsive fullsize" src="/Content/images/3.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-inverse">
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#our"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Our Friesians</a></li>
            <li><a href="#stock"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Stock</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Help <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Contact Details</li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span> Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Directions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <div class="container-fluid">


This is the Index page.


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Added current attempt, and switched to a question that doesn't expect a Boolean reply. :)

Comment: I answered it. :) Don't know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you have css for this.

Comment: Thanks Quentin ... It' just using the bootstrap.css... Playing with ideas here: http://ellispark.craigkeen.com/ ...

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest possible way to do it. You can just make the image max-width: 1200px, but that could be a problem down the line. I'm pretty sure this has been asked, and answered already. I'm too lazy to find it.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mlp{
    /*The next line controls the fit of the image.*/
    max-width: 100%;
}
#container{
    /*The next line controls the max of the container.
    Change it to the value you want.*/
    max-width: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
/*media query suggested as an alternative to the above.*/
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  #mlp {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  #container {
    max-width: 480px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <img id="mlp" src="http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/4163/01an1.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are css media queries that would switch out the image with hiding instead, but it's more code. Media queries should be placed at the bottom to take precedence when they're needed.

Comment: I saw this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651467/how-can-i-get-my-page-headers-to-resize-using-responsive-layout ---- but not sure where the "@media(max-width: 480px)...." goes. That's new to me. Is that CSS?

Comment: In your style tag/file. Like in my answer. You can mix that answer with this one to handle all sizes.

Comment: @Craig - It is a `media query`. It tells the browser to use different styles depending on the width of the browser. It is mainly used for responsive design.

Comment: @Craig media queries are ok. You probably don't need them to just have an image resize to a max width like in your high tech example. :) Media queries are better when you want text to be large on small screens or something like that which is the reverse of what you want.

Comment: Thanks! And, great news! I am thinking of doing a YouTube video on how to generate these detailed diagrams, but ... limitations of YouTube will hinder this. So, media queries might not be the right way to go for my example?

Comment: Oh WTF. Now I understand. I think Youtube may have to upgrade to handle those, while the internet will require an overhaul.